# How to add a 1d Array to a Dictionary of 2d Arrays for a Specific Dictionary Key?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary where each value is a 2D list, and I want to add a 1D list to a specific key. For example, how do I add `[3, 7.0]` to entry 1 in this dictionary example?

```py
 # Original dictionary
 dictionary = {1: [[2, 5.95], [3, 4.72]], 2: [[1, 5.95], [5,3.52]]}

 # Dictionary after adding [3, 7.0] to entry 1
 dictionary = {1: [[2, 5.95], [3, 4.72], [3,7.0]], 2: [[1, 5.95], [5,3.52]]}
```

Comment: `dictionary[1].append([3, 7.0])`?

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionary indexing in python

```
dictionary = {1: [[2, 5.95], [3, 4.72]], 2: [[1, 5.95], [5,3.52]]}
dictionary[1].append([3,7.0])

print(dictionary)
>> {1: [[2, 5.95], [3, 4.72], [3,7.0]], 2: [[1, 5.95], [5,3.52]]}
```